# Выбор перехода между стэйтами по String

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

Как реализовать метод `select`, чтобы отрабатывались переходы `selectOne`, `selectTwo` при вызове метода?

xml:

```
<action-state id="selectAction">
    <evaluate expression="userSelectHandler.select()" />
    <transition on="selectOne" to="one" />
    <transition on="selectTwo" to="two" />
</action-state>

<view-state id="one" />
<view-state id="two" />
```

Java-класс:

```
@Component
public class UserSelectHandler {

    public String select() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так

```
//Явно задано имя для компонента
@Component("selectAction")
public class UserSelectHandler {

    //Фабрика
    private org.springframework.webflow.action.EventFactorySupport eventFactorySupport = new org.springframework.webflow.action.EventFactorySupport();
    //Обрати внимание на возвращаемый тип
    public org.springframework.webflow.execution.Event select() {
        // идём по транзакции selectOne
        return   eventFactorySupport.event(this,"selectOne");
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот спасибо большое:)

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал как-то так:

```
public class Transition extends Event {
    public Transition(Object source, String id) {
        super(source, id);
    }

public Transition(Object source, String id, AttributeMap<Object> attributes) {
    super(source, id, attributes);
}

public static Transition go(String idTransition) {
    RequestContext context = RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext();

    Map<String, Object> contextMap = context.getFlowScope().asMap();
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : contextMap.entrySet()) {
        map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    Object source = context.getCurrentEvent().getSource();
    AttributeMap attributeMap = new LocalAttributeMap(map);
    return new Transition(source, idTransition, attributeMap);
    }
}
```

Остается только вопрос, как сохранить изменения в объекте, после вызова метода, например:

```
<evaluate expression="userMainHandler.select(user)" />
```